# Is there any way to retrieve tweet activity using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is there any way to retrive tweet activity (Impressions, Total engagements) of my own tweets by using tweepy (or maybe any other twitter library for python).

I'm using this simple code, but i couldn't found any way to retrive tweet activity:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this feature is available to the [Engagement API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/engagement-api/overview) which is only for Enterprise/Business accounts

> The Engagement API provides access to Tweet impression and engagement metrics.